# Why am I getting the VSTS load test error "part of the cookie is invalid" on every request?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, azure-devops, session-cookies, load-testing

I share my cookies between two different ASP.Net web sites by doing this:

```
    Response.Cookies("NET_SessionId").Domain = "**********.com"
    Response.Cookies("NET_SessionId").Path = "/"
```

This works fine in practice, but when I run a load test on VSTS using a working web test, the log is full of these:

```
W, 2560, 15, 2017/10/18, 15:40:58.796, vstsloadagent0\QTAgent32_40.exe, WebLoadTestAdapter: The response to 'https://*******************' set an invalid cookie 'NET_SessionId=': The 'Domain'='.**********.com' part of the cookie is invalid.
```

Here is just the error:

> The response to 'https://*******************' set an invalid cookie
>   'NET_SessionId=':  The 'Domain'='.**********.com' part of the cookie
>   is invalid.

It appears that this happens on every request. Note the dot before the domain name in the error message. That is different from what I specify in my code.

Comment: Show the actual error message. The redacted messages you show appear to be hiding the problem. Or at least be more careful about how you display the redacted versions. Why are there two full stops ( `.` ) in the error and just one in the value assigned at the top of the question?

Comment: It seems that I can't reproduce this issue. 1. Create a web form project 2. Add code to Page_load method 3. Do load test on VSTS. Can you share a simple project that can reproduce this issue?

Comment: @AdrianHHH Please see the last paragraph where I indicated that the dot in the error message is different than what I specified in my code. I included this because I thought it might be relevant.

Comment: @starain-MSFT I spend some time trying to come up with one, but when I recorded my web test the ASP_SessionId cookie was not there. This is a big old project that has been upgraded over the years. I'm not sure specifically which app settings cause that cookie to be generated.

Comment: @KeithWalton How do you check the cookie?